# Discord.py random meme API

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Trying to make a random meme command.

Tried 2 different ways, both end up with the same error.

discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'test' raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10015): Unknown Webhook

Both of my commands

```
async def meme(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    content = requests.get("https://meme-api.com/gimme").text
    data = json.loads(content,)
    meme = discord.Embed(title=f"{data['title']}")
    await interaction.followup.send(embed=meme)

and

@bot.tree.command()
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Meme', description=None)

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/wholesomememes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            
            
            embed.set_image(url=res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            
            await interaction.followup.send(embed=embed, content=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working code is below, tbh idk what i did but ended up Alt+z and worked on original code, fixed color=discord.Colour.random() and it worked :D

```
async def meme(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    content = requests.get("https://meme-api.com/gimme").text
    data = json.loads(content)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{data['title']}", color=discord.Colour.random()).set_image(url=f"{data['url']}")
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```